# Prove that $E(g(X)(X-\mu) ) \geq 0$

Tags: probability, statistics

If X is a random variable with finite mean $\mu$ and g(x) is a nondecreasing function, then  $E(g(X)(X-\mu) ) \geq 0$

Source of the question: casella and berger statistical inference page 191

How to prove this inequality? I don't understand the below proof. So I am wondering whether there exists some better method.

[image]

Comment: You want an explanation, right? Consider the sign of $X-\mu,$ they may be also assuming $g$ is a positive function.

Comment: @WilliamM. The textbook doesn't mention g is a positive function.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a mistake. If $g$ is always negative, for instance, then when $X - \mu$ is positive, $g(X) (X - \mu) \leq g(\mu) (X - \mu)$ opposite to what the book is using. Obviously, in this case the inequality seems false.

Comment: Also, add the text book title, and page, so if we have it, we can check it.

Comment: I believe there is a minimization principle at play here.

Comment: @WilliamM. added. Thanks! Casella and berger statistical inference page 191

Comment: The proof is wrong but the inequality is correct. Since $g$ is increasing, $g(x) - g(\mu)$ and $x - \mu$ have the same sign, therefore their product is positive and taking expectation the inequality follows. The inequality does not follow from the written argument unless $g$ is also assumed positive.

Comment: @WilliamM. Excellent explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the expectation of the product of two increasing functions of $X$ is greater or equal to the product of their expectations. See ["A special case: the Harris inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality)
.

Let's do this special case. First we observe that it is enough to prove
$$E[(g(X) -g(\mu))(X-\mu)]\ge 0,$$

because $E[g(\mu) (X-\mu)] = g(\mu) E[X-\mu]  =0$.

Next:

i. On the event $\{X\ge \mu\}$: $g(X)-g(\mu)\ge0$ and $X-\mu\ge 0$. So the product  $(g(X)-g(\mu))(X-\mu)\ge 0$

ii. On the event $\{X < \mu\}$: $g(X)-g(\mu) \le 0$ and $X-\mu<0$. Therefore  $(g(X)-g(\mu))(X-\mu) \ge 0$.

Bottom line: in either case the random variable whose expectation we take is nonnegative. Therefore its expectation is nonnegative.